# Double-wrapping Windows8 grid view

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, variablesizedwrapgrid

I'm working on a Windows 8 application and i have to create a different-sized tiles view. An issue is that i need my view to be double-wrapped: first, it should be wrapped horizontally (ie, each column should be 2 tiles in width). Such a view is going to be a very tall column. Next, it should wrap vertically.

The sketch of a view i'm going to create is given below. Are there any Win8 controls able to provide the described behavior ?

I've tried to use `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, but it seems it's unable to double-wrap it.

[image]

Comment: If the workaround is going to be really complex it might be easier to use a grid or StackPanel containing separate VariableSizedWrapGrid for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the time has passed and i've got no better solution than creating a custom columned model and using a grid with few VariableGridViews (one VariableGridViews per column).

Maybe, my XAML will help somebody.

```
<controls:VariableGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">

    <controls:VariableGridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <controls:VariableGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">

                <controls:VariableGridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Width}">
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="{Binding WidthPixels}" Height="{Binding HeightPixels}"></Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:VariableGridView.ItemTemplate>

                <controls:VariableGridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    ItemHeight="150"
                                    ItemWidth="150"
                                    MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" Height="768"
                                    AllowDrop="True"
                                    Tapped="VariableSizedWrapGrid_Tapped"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </controls:VariableGridView.ItemsPanel>
            </controls:VariableGridView>

        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:VariableGridView.ItemTemplate>

</controls:VariableGridView>
```

Model source code looks like (truncated)

```
public class TilesCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<ITile> Tiles {get; private set;}
}



public class ColumnedListModel
{
    ObservableCollection<TilesCollection> m_columns = new ObservableCollection<TilesCollection>();


    public ObservableCollection<TilesCollection> Columns
    {
        get
        {
            return m_columns;
        }
    }
    // ....
}
```